# Comparing a month and year sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I am making project in c# .net where I am badly stuck in a database query.

I have a date column in my table of my database in which i have stored the date with datatype `varchar(50)` and passed `(convert(varchar(8),getdate(),5)` as default so it gives me a date in `dd-MM-YY` e.g `28-03-17`.

Now the user input a month  format `MM` and year  format `YY`" in textbox only (NOT DAY) and in case if the user entries `(month,year)` are equal to month and year of database table then show the all data.

I know I have to first extract month and year from table date and then compare with user input. From searching I came to know that by using `Year(DateField)` I can extract year and Month `Month(Date Field)` from date field.

I am using below query but it isn't right at all.

```
 "select * from table1 
 where YEAR(Time=convert(varchar(8),getdate(),5))='" + textBox1.Text + 
 "' AND MONTH(Time=convert(varchar(8),getdate(),5))='" + textBox2.Text + "'";
```

Where 'Time' is the name of my date field in database.The big problem is that I don't know how to compare year and month in this format that I have used.

Comment: I got many errors using this query.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but instead of adding information in the comments you can [edit] your question.

Comment: getDate is sql-server function ...not mysql .. please confirm you db tag ..

Comment: You can do this: **Add days in the format you said (dd) to the beginning of your input string and compare it with the record in the DB.** I mean add 01 to the beginning of your string, this way no matter what the day in the DB is, your date will be equal or smaller than that.

Comment: And you have a huge sql injection vulnerability by passing in a textbox's text value directly into a SQL statement...  To your actual point, What is the format of the text you are storing?   And can you change the datatype stored to `date` instead of `varchar(50)` or is that set in stone?

Comment: This is my very first project and i know i have made foolish mistakes.I have to compare the dates by using varchar(50) @Tim.

Comment: Is date stored in your database is in format `dd-MM-YY` ? or it looks something like `2017-03-09 01:05:20.460` ?

Comment: what's the `getdate()` for? I though you want to compare user input with the value in your `Time` value in db?

Comment: It saved in " 28-02-17 " "DD-MM-YY" @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: You've made this much harder than it needs to be. Keep in mind that dates are simply a number that represents how many time increments have elapsed since the epoc date. There are built in functions (in both T-SQL and C#) that make it easy to manipulate dates and perform date calculations. You don't need to worry about formatting for display until it is time to display the date value (there are built in methods for that as well).

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the value of `Time` column to DateTime and get the YEAR out of it. 
You will get the year value in four digits, like 2017. To convert it to two digits you need to divide it by 100 using modulo operator.

```
//Preparing parameterized query to avoid SQL injection.
var sqlQuery = "select * from Tokens where  (YEAR(Convert(datetime,Time,5)) % 100) = @year  AND MONTH(Convert(datetime,Time,5)) = @month";

//Preparing command and adding parameters with the values.
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@year", textBox1.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@month", textBox2.Text);
```

Now you can use this command to retrieve the data from the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chetan Ranpariya it worked very well!..and also to everyone who gave their suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the date in the VARCHAR column is stored as `dd-MM-YY` (as you mentioned) then this query should work:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE SUBSTRING(-DateColumn-,4,2) = textBox1.text 
AND SUBSTRING(-DateColumn-,7,2) = textBox2.text
```

Since you're storing the date as text, there's no need to convert anything. You should just be able to do a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

First, sql server has a datetime data type so you should not be storing dates in your database as a string.

If you did do that, you would do something like:

```
select * from table1 
 where YEAR(Time)=" + textBox1.Text + 
 " AND MONTH(Time)=" + textBox2.Text;
```

Year and time both return ints so you do not need to delimit the text from your textboxes with a single quote.

One more thing, previous commenters are right, you should never directly take the text from a textbox and inject it into a sql string. It opens you up for sql injection attacks. Instead you should be using parameters.